# NetLogo 6 and the rnd extension

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to update my model to NL 6 because the automatic update failed (mostly due to syntax for anonymous procedures). My model uses the rnd extension which now apparently comes bundled with NetLogo, but the example from [the manual](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/rnd.html) still mentions this:

```
extensions[rnd]

to go

  let pairs [ [ "A" 0.2 ] [ "B" 0.8 ] ]
repeat 25 [
  ; report the first item of the pair selected using
  ; the second item (i.e., `last ?`) as the weight
  type first rnd:weighted-one-of-list pairs [ last ? ]
]

end
```

This results in an error because "nothing named ? has been defined". I have been able to convert other things like foreach and n-values, but I am struggling with this example to the new notation required by NetLogo 6. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We missed a few cases when converting the `rnd` extension manual for bundling it with NetLogo. This will be fixed in NetLogo 6.0.1. In the meanwhile, you can refer to the most current version of the manual on GitHub:

https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension/blob/hexy/README.md

In your specific case, the NetLogo 6 syntax would be:

```
rnd:weighted-one-of-list pairs [ [p] -> last p ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nicolas.